# If char$R=n$, show that $\mathbb{Z}1_R\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $1_R$ be the identity of a ring $R$ and let $\mathbb{Z}1_R=\{k1_R\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

If char$R=n$, show that $\mathbb{Z}1_R\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$.

So my thought is I just have to think of some rule for $\sigma:\mathbb{Z}1_R\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n$ and show that $\sigma$ is an isomorphism I will be done.

So clearly $\sigma(k1_R)=(k\mod n$) would be onto.

Also $\sigma(k1_R+m1_R)=\sigma((k+m)1_R)=(k+m)\mod n = (k\mod n) + (m\mod n) = \sigma(k1_R)+\sigma(m1_R)$

and $\sigma(k1_R\cdot m1_R)=\sigma((k\cdot m)1_R)=(k\cdot m)\mod n = (k\mod n) \cdot (m\mod n) = \sigma(k1_R)\cdot\sigma(m1_R)$

assuming what I've done so far is correct, I am not sure how to show it is one to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to go the other way around: define the map
$$
\chi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to R,
\qquad
k\mapsto k1_R
$$
and prove that $\ker\chi=n\mathbb{Z}$. Since the image of $\chi$ is $\mathbb{Z}1_R$, the homomorphism theorem allows to finish up.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply the first isomorphism theorem now.